# Show that ellipses $5x^2 +6xy+5y^2=C$ are integral curves of the ODE: $(5x+3y)+(3x+5y)y'=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

The second question asks: What are its solution curves?

These questions were extracted from Ordinary Differential equations: Garrett Birkhoff.

What I did:
I differentiated the first equation (of the ellipse) and got the differential equation shown, but it was too simple, so I am not quite sure that that was the expected way to prove it.

Also, I tried to do it the other way around (finding the first equation from the differential equation given). However, I could only get to the normal form of the differential equation, and I can not figure out which method should I use:

$y'=\dfrac{-5x-3y}{3x+5y}$

On the other hand, what are its solution curves? I could not understand what this question expected me to do, so I supposed it meant finding the solution curves of the orthogonal trajectories, so I just replaced the "inverse" of the slope given (normal form of differential equation) $y'=\frac{3x+5y}{5x+3y}$ in the ODE given at first, $(5x+3y)+(3x+5y)y'=0$.

I really appreciate your answer

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$(5x+3y)+(3x+5y)y'=0 \quad \iff \quad (5x+3y)dx+(3x+5y)dy=0$$
is an [exact equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_differential_equation) because:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(5x+3y)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(xx+5y)=3
$$ 
So the solution is $f(x,y)=C$ where $f(x,y)$ is a function such that
$$
\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}=(5x+3y) \quad \mbox{and}\quad \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}=(3x+5y) 
$$

that is exactly $f(x,y)=5x^2+6xy+5y^2$. And the solution curves (or [integral curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation#Solutions)) are the ellipse of equation $5x^2+6xy+5y^2=C$

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it is sufficient to do what you did first, just differentiate, nothing else is needed. Since the ellipses plus the origin cover the whole plane you have found all the invariant sets (the expression "solution curve" is rarely used).